# Inverted video player's navigation bar when video streaming

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, video-streaming

I'm building a video chat application using Node, Express, Socket.io, and WebRTC by following this tutorial: [Link blog](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/building-a-video-chat-app-with-node-js-socket-io-webrtc-26f46b213017)

So on my edge browser, after i enabled the video stream on my application and my webcam is activated, i noticed that when i right click on the video area (video element) and click on show all controls, i found that video player navigation bar is inverted.

Do you have any explication on why the nav bar is **inverted**? (check theses screenshots for inversed nav bar [screenshot **1**](https://ibb.co/0GyJYdj)  &  [screenshot **2**](https://ibb.co/PcpkbR1))

---

Below are my codes:

**room.ejs:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>videoChatApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c939d0e917.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.3.1/dist/peerjs.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      const ROOM_ID = "<%= roomId %>";
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo">
        <h3>Video Chat</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="main__left">
        <div class="videos__group">
          <div id="video-grid"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="options">
          <div class="options__left">
            <div id="stopVideo" class="options__button">
              <i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i>
            </div>
            <div id="muteButton" class="options__button">
              <i class="fa fa-microphone"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="options__right">
            <div id="inviteButton" class="options__button">
              <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main__right">
        <div class="main__chat_window">
          <div class="messages"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="main__message_container">
          <input
            id="chat_message"
            type="text"
            autocomplete="off"
            placeholder="Type message here..."
          />
          <div id="send" class="options__button">
            <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

**script.js:**

```
let myVideoStream;
const videoGrid = document.getElementById("video-grid");
const myVideo = document.createElement("video");
myVideo.muted = true;
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: true,
})
    .then((stream) => {
        myVideoStream = stream;
        addVideoStream(myVideo, stream);
    });

const addVideoStream = (video, stream) => {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
        video.play();
        videoGrid.append(video);
    });
};
```

**server.js:**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'));



app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect(`/${uuidv4()}`);
});

app.get("/:room", (req, res) => {
    res.render("room", { roomId: req.param.room });
});



app.listen(3030, () => {
    console.log('Server is runing on port 3030');
})
```

**style.css:**

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600&display=swap");

:root {
  --main-darklg: #1d2635;
  --main-dark: #161d29;
  --primary-color: #2f80ec;
  --main-light: #eeeeee;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 8vh;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--main-darklg);
}

.logo > h3 {
  color: var(--main-light);
}

.main {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 92vh;
  display: flex;
}

.main__left {
  flex: 0.7;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.videos__group {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: var(--main-dark);
}

video {
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  width: 900px;
  object-fit: cover;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.options {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  background-color: var(--main-darklg);
}

.options__left {
  display: flex;
}

.options__right {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.options__button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: var(--main-light);
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
}

.background__red {
  background-color: #f6484a;
}

.main__right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0.3;
  background-color: #242f41;
}

.main__chat_window {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.main__chat_window::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.main__message_container {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main__message_container > input {
  height: 50px;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border: none;
}

.messages {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 1.5rem;
}

.message {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.message > b {
  color: #eeeeee;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.message > b > i {
  margin-right: 0.7rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.message > span {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#video-grid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#showChat {
  display: none;
}

.header__back {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  top: 17px;
  left: 28px;
  color: #fff;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .main__right {
    display: none;
  }
  .main__left {
    width: 100%;
    flex: 1;
  }

  video {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #showChat {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

Comment: this typically comes from CSS. Search for scaleX(-1)

Comment: @PhilippHancke i didn't find `scaleX` in my css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying a 180 degree rotation to the element (i.e. mirroring it)
by using `transform: rotateY(180deg)` in your CSS file which also rotates the controls.
For WebRTC usage the common approach to solving this is not to use the build-in controls of the video element.